# Flutter: how to execute multiple functions in a single button

Tags: flutter, dart

in Flutter I have made a custom button that does a small animation when pressing it. The issue is that when I add a `VoidCallBack` function, which is a parameter that I give to the button widget, to the same `onTap`, then the function does not get executed whilst the animation does.

I did find this question ( [how do we execute two function in single button pressed in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069088/how-do-we-execute-two-function-in-single-button-pressed-in-flutter)) that seems to be similar to mine but I have tried the suggestions and they do not work for me.

Here is a code snippet of when Im trying to use the button widget:

```
MyButton (
  onTap = () {
    print(_isSelected);
    setState(() {
      _isSelected[0] = !_isSelected[0];
    });
  },
)
```

Also I dont know if it makes a difference but Ive tried it both with and without the `setState` part.

Then in the button itself I do:

```
onTap: () {
    widget.onTap;
    setState(() {
      _clicked = !_clicked;
    });
  },
```

I also tried to do this, like in the other stackOverflow question which had the same result:

```
onTap: () => [
    widget.onTap,
    {
      setState(() {
        _clicked = !_clicked;
      })
    }
  ],
```

Though it does work if I only use the parameter: `onTap: widget.onTap,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually how I do it.

```
onTap: () {
    widget.onTap();
    your_function_here();
  },
```

Comment: That does work, why is it that you need to put the brackets at the end of `widget.onTap();` but if I do `onTap: widget.onTap,` I dont need it?

Comment: `widget.onTap` is just variable  and `widget.onTap()` is a method that will call

Comment: If you're using function body you have to use a method call. And I believe arrow function always try to execute whatever inside of that body. A better explanation of that can be read here https://medium.com/run-dart/dart-dartlang-introduction-functions-and-fat-arrow-expression-d9ce8e22c2da

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a constructor which takes onTap function as a parameter.

```
class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function onTap;
  const MyButton ({Key? key, this.onTap,}) : super(key: key);
}
```

Since the onTap parameter needs a function as argument, you simply write a function that runs your functions.

```
MyButton(
  onTap: () {
    your_function1();
    your_function2();
  },
)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Declare function variable:

```
 final Function onTap;
```

and call widget.onTap with round brackets as below:

```
 onTap: (){
 widget.onTap();
 setState(() {
    _clicked = !_clicked;
  });
 }
```